# simple WSDL wrapper for HTTP process?

Tags: wsdl

Suppose I have a simple HTTP form that uses POST to pass some parameters
and returns OK or BAD (which I do).  A client wants this to be published
as a WSDL description.  Looking into WSDL I see an infinite morass of
formalisms, but no practical tools.

Surely there must be a simple way to create a wrapper for a simple form processor?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a POST of the form data, do you use HTML to send the users data? If yes then you have to change both client and server. The idea you encapsulate the form's data in a SOAP envelope and send it over HTTP. So I am not sure what you mean by

> a wrapper for a simple form processor

Comment: take any service which is invoked by a simple HTTP form, ie: <form action=xx method=post><input name=foo type=text></form> and create a WSDL description so that an external service would be able to invoke it.

Comment: You are talking about a service that serves HTML content, right? And the client sends an HTTP POST with the form's values in attribute-value pairs? In this case, a new web service should be created. Unless you are using AJAX, which is XML over HTTP, so in this case you already have a web service, but this is a REST web service and they do not have a wsdl deployed. Check out REST web services for the latter case